# Is there a way to check whether a VideoPlayerController from the Flutter video-player package is already disposed?

Tags: flutter, video-player, flutter-video-player

At a point in my code I now that I won't need a `VideoPlayerController` anymore but I'm not sure whether or not a `VideoPlayerController` is already disposed. Currently, I call the `dispose()` method but when the `VideoPlayerController` is already disposed that throws the error:

```
2021-04-08 23:35:07.602 1898-2090/com.learningleaflets.anatomyleaflet E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: A VideoPlayerController was used after being disposed.
    Once you have called dispose() on a VideoPlayerController, it can no longer be used.
    #0      ChangeNotifier._debugAssertNotDisposed.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:117:9)
    #1      ChangeNotifier._debugAssertNotDisposed (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:123:6)
    #2      ChangeNotifier.dispose (package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart:212:12)
    #3      VideoPlayerController.dispose (package:video_player/video_player.dart:383:11)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

I don't want that error to fill my logs, so is there a way to check whether a `VideoPlayerController` is already disposed to avoiding calling `dispose()` on it?

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of the error being displayed. The error means that you tried to use the `VideoPlayerController` after it was disposed. Could be done by mistake also if more than one video is using the same controller. You dispose of it in the first video, then try to use the same one to play the second video, then this error is thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use try-catch block

```
try{
_videoController.dispose();
//Do something
}
catch(e){
//Do something
}
```

Comment: What should I do in the catch?

Comment: Depends on your use cases.
If you use this, no error will fill your logs as required by your ques.

Comment: its not catched in the dispose method 

```
try {
      videoNotifier.videoPlayerController
          .removeListener(videoNotifier.listener);

      videoNotifier.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    } catch (e) {
      log('Err : dispose custom controller $e');
    } finally {
      super.dispose();
    }
```